# i.i.d. sequences satisfies the weak law but not strong law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, law-of-large-numbers

Is there an example of an i.i.d. sequence of random variables $X_n$ so that $S_n/n\to 0$ in probability but $S_n/n$ does not converge a.s.?

This post has an answer in which the sequences are independent but not i.i.d.

[Sequence satisfies weak law of large numbers but doesn't satisfy strong law of large numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288502/sequence-satisfies-weak-law-of-large-numbers-but-doesnt-satisfy-strong-law-of-l?rq=1)

We know from the strong law of large numbers that if $EX_1=c\in [-\infty,\infty]$, then $S_n/n\to EX_1$ a.s.

Hence such an example must have $EX_1^+=\infty$ and $EX_1^-=\infty$.

Comment: Wikipedia has a number of examples in the section "Differences between the weak and large..." of this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law.