# An example: The average of a sequence of random variables does not converge to the mean of each variable in the sequence almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_n, n\geq 2$ be a random variable taking the values $n,0$ or $-n$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{2n \log (n)}, 1 - \frac{1}{n \log (n)}$ and $\frac{1}{2n \log (n)}$, respectively. Define the sum $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$. Suppose we know:
$$\mathbb{P}\{|X_n| \geq n \,\,\text{infinitely often}\} = 1$$
Why does this imply:
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} \neq 0\right\} = 1$$

---

Context:
I'm reading about an example of a random sequence that satisfies the weak LLN but not the strong LLN. This example is 15.3 in Stoyanov's Counterexamples in Probability. I have found more detail in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288502/sequence-satisfies-weak-law-of-large-numbers-but-doesnt-satisfy-strong-law-of-l?rq=1) but not enough to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$X_{n}=S_{n}-S_{n-1},$$

therefore
$$|X_{n}| \le |S_{n}|+|S_{n-1}|$$

Therefore, if $|X_n|=n$, or $|S_{n-1}| \ge n/2$ or $|S_n| \ge n/2$, otherwise $|X_n|<n$. That means

$$\{X_n=n\} \subseteq \left\{\frac{|S_n|}{n}\ge\frac{1}{2}  \right\} \bigcup\left\{\frac{|S_{n-1}|}{n}\ge\frac{1}{2}  \right\}.$$

By Borel-Cantelli, is easily seen that
$$\mathbb{P}\{X_n=n \text{ infinitely often}\}=1,$$

then there are, with probability $1$, infinitely many $n$ for which either $\frac{|S_n|}{n}\ge \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{|S_{n-1}|}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}$.But note that if $\frac{|S_{n-1}|}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{|S_{n-1}|}{n-1}=\frac{n}{n-1} \frac{|S_{n-1}|}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}.$

We see that, almost surely, we have infinite $n$'s for which $\frac{|S_n|}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2}$, therefore $S_n/n$ cannot converge to $0$.

Comment: That should be $X_n = n$, not $X_n = n + 1$, same for $|X_n|$.

Comment: @Sam corrected it.